# Starting container failed: subnet sandbox join failed for \"10.255.0.0/16\"

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am trying to port my "normal" container I run using:

```
docker run -d -p 8001:80 myImage:20181011123308
```

to a docker service, so I can use docker secrets. My service is running on a linux machine and should be exposed to the internet with port 8001:

```
docker service create --with-registry-auth --network my-overlay --name kinoheld --publish published=8001,target=80 --tty myImage:20181011123308
```

After a long search I found, that docker is logging the following error:

> Oct 11 16:35:32 ns3311367.ip-5-135-162.eu dockerd[1621]:
>   time="2018-10-11T16:35:32.578017228+02:00" level=error msg="fatal task
>   error" error="starting container failed: subnet sandbox join failed
>   for \"10.255.0.0/16\": error creating vxlan interface: operation not
>   supported" module="node/agent/taskmanager"
>   node.id=kafpbh873owp6e3us4zx1gghg service.id=rel9onyvcc82rrk7jsho9pgnz
>   task.id=whnjff89hr7d6n4phvd1ead4d

But I don't know what the error means exactly and how to resolve it. Is anyone able to help me with this error and can tell me, what the problem might be?

I am currently running docker version `17.05.0-ce`

My debian host is running linux:

```
uname -r
4.9.87-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was a problem with the installed linux kernel.

The VPS / root server hoster OVH does use a custom  kernel, which did not have activated vxlan support.

Answer (score 3):

From https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/issues/1765#issuecomment-464223535

Check if you have `vx-` interface on host:

```
ip link show | grep vx
```

If so, delete them, it worked for me:

```
ip link delete vx-xxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing [Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on ARMv8 SMP](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-1005-raspi) solved this for me (RPi3B, Ubuntu Server 22.04):

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-raspi
```

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71454262/1461850)